# How to undo or ignore component changes in Figma when publishing asset library?

Tags: figma, asset-management, library

In making changes to some components, I edited the wrong button-component for a second. Figma is tracking the change, and wants to publish it to update the library it's in. I don't want it to update, I want to ignore the change or revert it back to the original. I know I can un-check the box to publish, but I don't want to have to keep track of always un-checking that box.

I think there must be some way to undo, ignore, or reset the changes so the edit is no longer tracked. How do I do that?

[image: Screenshot of Figma publish asset change]

[image: Button component with changes not yet published helper text]

Answer (score 0):

If simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> undo history is not enough, you can restore the previous published version of the file. Unfortunately, that would mean resetting all changes (but you can restore them back if necessary) in the file, not only changes to a specific component. There is no way to reset only specific changes. Each publish event creates a new version of the file you can restore:

[image: Figma version history: restore Components Published version]

Answer (score 0):

There's a very easy way to do this without deleting the component. This is what you can do: (Figma will make these prefixed components Private to the file when the styles and components are pblished)

- **add a (.) period in front of the component layer's name**
- **add an (_) underscore in front of the component layer's name**

This is very similar to adding comments while programming, adding a prefix such as // etc. can be used to comment out code snippets.

More details can be found here
https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025508373#private

Also, please note (copied from Figma's website):

> If you add a period or underscore after a style or component is
> published, Figma will remove it from your library the next time you
> publish changes to the library.